# React navigation destroy screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have a `button tab navigator` `Profile screen` and `BarcodeScanner screen`, after scanning a barcode i redirect the user to `Profile screen` but the camera is still working and it keeps scanning barcodes even the scene is the `Profile screen`.

I don't know what should i do or how to close `Camera/barcode scanner`
I use `Expo barcode Scanner`

**Code**

```
  import { BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      />
    </View>

  _handleBarCodeRead = (data) => {
    alert(`Bar code with type ${data.type} and data ${data.data} has been scanned!`);
      this.props.navigation('Profile')     
  }
```

Comment: It’d be good to add your code to further explain. I know react-navigation (if that’s what you’re using) have a .replace() method which may achieve the outcome you’re looking for. But please explain this further, help us, help you.

Comment: I updated with the code of barcode, i use react native navigation, but i don't know the problem related to expo or navigation or react native itself

Comment: Would that be [this one?](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

Comment: Sorrrrry i use react navigation https://reactnavigation.org/en/

Comment: No worries. So change `this.props.navigation('Profile')` to `this.props.navigation.replace('Profile')` and let me know the outcome.

Comment: `replace()` function is only used on `stack Navigator` while i use `tab Navigator`

Comment: Another thing to suggest, if you run `goBack()` rather than `navigate()`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem where when i navigate the camera is still `mounted` so it keeps scanning `barcode`

I used `this.props.isFocused` to fix my issue

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation'

render() {
    const { isFocused } = this.props
    return (
       <View>
         { isFocused && <RNCamera  ... />  }
       </View
     ) }


export default withNavigationFocus(Camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stacknavigator as a root navigator, then inside have 2 screens the first one being the tabs and the second one the barcode scanner. Everytime you navigate to the barcode scanner (via an user interaction in a screen od the tabnavigator , maybe a button with "scan Barcode" , or something like that), the barcode screen shoul popup like a modal. Then when you are done you just goBack() and the screen closes / unmounts